# Why is navigator.geolocation null in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, geolocation

In my case it was because it was a site on the intranet and it was displaying all intranet sites in compatibility mode. When I switched this off then it worked

NB you can also prevent this happening via

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marking as answered, the answer is in the question